# x86-64-v4 in ubuntu?

Tags: architecture

Kindly guide me how to use x86-64-v4 architecture in ubuntu. Does ubuntu already provides installer for this architecture? I have i5-1135G7 CPU with igpu and 8GB RAM and nvme ssd. Hp 15-dw3031nx

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Considering they only started experimenting with V3 a few days ago (https://www.phoronix.com/news/Ubuntu-x86-64-v3-Experiment), don't expect v4 anytime soon.

Comment: Can I build it myself?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/blog/optimising-ubuntu-performance-on-amd64-architecture